# Создание сессии и авторизация. Смена пароля- а пользователь авторизован

Tags: php, сессия

Я создаю в сессии значение `Authorized=1`, когда пользователь авторизуется.

Пользователь хранит пароль где-то у себя в блокнотике. Вдруг зашёл вор- увидел его пароль и авторизовался в системе. Наш пользователь об этом узнал и сменил пароль. Но так как в сессии вора `Autorized=1` , то он продолжает безболезненно работать с аккаунтом.

**Что здесь делать? как избежать такой ситуации?**

Лазить каждый раз к базе и проверять комбинацию логин/пароль не хочется.

В контакте, например, если откроешь страницы в разных браузерах и из одного сменишь пароль, то следующая страница на втором браузере уже не откроется, т.е. там другой механизм.

Answer (score 1):

предлагаю сделать так.

для вора и для пользователя каждый браузер открывает отдельную сессию. Так что понадобится проверять пару значений из обшей базы сессий.

К примеру, создаете значение `sessionKey = acb123` в зависимости от пользователя. Можно этот ключ менять при смене пароля каждый раз.

Когда клиент заходит в систему, вы берете этот ключ и передаете сессии. Потом при каждом другом обращении проверяете это значение. Просто проверяете есть ли такое значение в базе. Не нужно проверять сопоставление логина и пароля. Можно эти ключи держать в отдельной таблице.

**когда пользователь меняет пароль, вы также меняете этот ключ.**

Что происходит. **Когда вор работает в системе** и переходит в другую ссылку, вы проверяете его ключ. Так как ключ изменился, вы его отбрасываете из системы.